# Bootstrap buttons with <a> tag don't group together

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

First, I am rather new to HTML so this may be simple.

```
<div class="btn-group pull-center" style="text-align:center">
        <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="button">Home</button>
        <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="button">Forum</button>
        <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="button">Bans</button>
        <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="button">Store</button>  
    <?php
        if($_SESSION['isLogged'] == true) {
            $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    ?>  <a href="logout.php"><button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="button">Hello, <?php $username ?></button></a>
        <a href="logout.php"><button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="button">Log out</button></a>

    <?php    }else {
    ?>  <a href="login.php"><button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="button">Log in</button></a><?php
        }           

        ?>
    </div>
```

Generally the btn-group class works and they group.  However, if I add an A tag to a button, that button will not group.

Here are some screenshots

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IUqn.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for Bootstrap. And I have no buttons here:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <a class="btn">Home</a>
  <a class="btn">Forum</a>
  <a class="btn">Bans</a>
  <a class="btn">Store</a>
  <a href="logout.php" class="btn">Hello username</a>
  <a href="logout.php" class="btn">Log out</a>
  <a href="login.php" class="btn">Log in</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're putting the .btn class inside a `<a>` tag. But, the twitter-bootstrap framework group buttons only if `.btn` elements are direct children of `.btn-group`. Indeed, the rule might be written with `.btn-group > .btn`.

Put the `.btn` class on your `<a>` tag and even remove this uselss button tag and it'll work. For example:

```
<div class="btn-group pull-center" style="text-align:center">
  <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="button">Home</a>
  <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="button">Forum</a>
  <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="button">Bans</a>
  <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="button">Store</a>  
  <a href="" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="button">Hello, Username</a>
  <a href="logout.php" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="button">Log out</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using buttons, just add the `btn` class to the `a` tag instead. Example:

```
<div class="btn-group pull-center" style="text-align:center">
  <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary">Home</a>
  <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary">Forum</a>
  <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary">Bans</a>
  <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary">Store</a>  
  <a href="logout.php" class="btn btn-large btn-primary">Hello, Username</a>
  <a href="logout.php" class="btn btn-large btn-primary">Log out</a>
  <a href="login.php" class="btn btn-large btn-primary">Log in</a>
</div>
```

**[Demo](http://bootply.com/74192)**